# Typescript: Infer type of the implementing class of an interface in the interface

Tags: typescript

So I'm trying to write this interface that each object that will be cached into redis in my application will have to implement.

To use it right now you'd write something like this:

```
class Base implements Cacheable<[number], Base> {
    ...
}
```

but is there any way to from the interface infer the type of Base from the implementing class so that it could look like this instead with typescript:

```
class Base implements Cacheable<[number]> {
     ...
}
```

Comment: [extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) ?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay the main issue with this is that the interface will be implemented by a wide variety of different classes that may have absolutely nothing in common except the function toCacheableObject and fromCacheableObject which returns an instance of the original type of the class implementing it, hence why I need the type in the first place, but many of those clases already extend other classes and it feels overkill to make it extend a class for just those two definitions.

Comment: Could you flesh this out into a [mcve] so that someone could tell when they have succeeded?  What is `Cacheable`?  If the question has a dependency on redis then maybe it should be tagged as such; otherwise you should remove references to external types or provide a toy implementation of them.

Comment: Expanding on jcalz's comment - I believe the direct answer to your specific question (can an interface infer the type that's implementing it) would be no, but it's possible that the meta-problem (can I avoid re-referencing the implementing type in the type parameters) is solvable, especially with the added context that jcalz requests